# Select2 .val function returning empty value when selected using 'closest' : jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have a table containing a checkbox , some text and a select2 dropdown. The user will select a checkbox and then select a value in select2 drop down. I'm trying to find out if the user has selected a value in the select2 box corresponding to the checked checkboxes.

Following is my code:

```js
var value = [{
  id: 0,
  text: 'enhancement'
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: 'bug'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'duplicate'
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: 'invalid'
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: 'wontfix'
}]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bulk_relationship_dropdown").select2({
    data: value
  })

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    jQuery(".bulk_relationship_dropdown").each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val() != "") {
        console.log(jQuery(this).val());
      }
    })

    $(".cb:checked").each(function() {
      var cb = $(this);
      if (cb.closest('tr').find('.bulk_relationship_dropdown').val() == "") {
        console.log("here"); //do something
      }
    })

  });


});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="submit">submit</button>
```

In the above code when I iterate through all the checkboxes `.val()` function gives me correct values. That is this portion.

```
jQuery(".bulk_relationship_dropdown").each(function() {
          if (jQuery(this).val() != "") {
            console.log(jQuery(this).val());
          }

        })
```

But when I find the select2 boxes corresponding to checked checkboxes like below the `.val()` function is always returning empty string.

```
$(".cb:checked").each(function() {
          var cb = $(this);
          if (cb.closest('tr').find('.bulk_relationship_dropdown').val() == "") {
            console.log("here"); //do something
          }
        })
```

What am i doing wrong?

**I'm using select2 3.5.2**

Comment: I have added working code snippet in the question

Comment: Sorry guys.. I haven't noted that..

Comment: Note that this problem doesn't exist in Select2 4.0, as we no longer automatically copy the classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select2 duplicates the classes on your `input` as part of a non-form-control structure it generates. That generated structure (currently a `span`) will be the first one in the jQuery set returned by `find`, and `val` only tries to read from the first element in the set, so will return `undefined`. Just add `input` to your selectors so you're finding your inputs instead (which select2 hides but keeps up-to-date):

```
cb.closest("tr").find("input.bulk_relationship_dropdown")
// --------------------^^^^^
```

Updated snippet:

```js
var value = [{
  id: 0,
  text: 'enhancement'
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: 'bug'
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: 'duplicate'
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: 'invalid'
}, {
  id: 4,
  text: 'wontfix'
}]

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bulk_relationship_dropdown").select2({
    data: value
  })

  $("#submit").click(function() {

    jQuery("input.bulk_relationship_dropdown").each(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val() != "") {
        console.log(jQuery(this).val());
      }
    })

    $(".cb:checked").each(function() {
      var cb = $(this);
      if (cb.closest('tr').find('input.bulk_relationship_dropdown').val() == "") {
        console.log("here"); //do something
      }
    })

  });


});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="cb">
    </td>
    <td>some random text</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" style="width: 120px" class="bulk_relationship_dropdown">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button id="submit">submit</button>
```